# i am leraning ejs and my variable in ejs file is giving error

Tags: javascript, ejs

i am leraning ejs and variable to add dynamic data in following code is KindofDay and on running server it is giving error KindOfDay is not defined. I want to add data on basis of app.js on to my ejs file but it is producing the error

```
<body>
    <h1>register</h1>
    <form action="/api/register" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="enter email" /><br />
      <input
        type="password"
        name="password"
        id="password"
        placeholder="enter password"
      /><br />
      <button type="submit">register</button>
    </form>
    <p><%=kindOfDay%></p>
    <a href="/api/login">login</a>
    <script>
      const form = document.querySelector('form')
      const email = document.querySelector('#email')
      const password = document.querySelector('#password')
      form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        fetch("/api/register", { 
      
      // Adding method type 
      method: "POST", 
        
      // Adding body or contents to send 
      body: JSON.stringify({ 
          email: email.value , 
          password: password.value ,  
      }), 
        
      // Adding headers to the request 
      headers: { 
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      } 
  }) 
    
  // Converting to JSON 
  .then(response => response.json()) 
    
  // Displaying results to console 
  .then(json => console.log(json)); 
      })
    </script>
  </body>
```

this is the code which is rendering the ejs file to update the kindOfDay variable

```
router
  .route("/register")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render('register')
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    console.log([req.body.password, req.body.email]);
    const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
    const checkUser = {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
    };
    const { value, error } = validateUser(checkUser);
    if (error) {
      status = "error"
      res.status(404).render('register' ,{kindOfDay : error.message});
    } else {
      user = users.find((u) => {
        if (u.email === req.body.email) {
          return u;
        }
      });
    }
    if (user) {
      res.status(404).json("userexist");
    } else {
      const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashPassword,
      };
      users.push(newUser);
      res.status(200).json("ok");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is rendering the template?

Comment: @shadowtime2000 i have updated the code